# Improve formatsize and space of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am trying to adjust spacing between 4 subplots of transmittance and reflection for Transverse magnetic and electric field waves. I added the 4 plots into 1 figure plot. My goal is to change the subplots margins so I don't get overlapping subplots. I used the code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


"DEFINE FRESNEL EQUATIONS"


"""Define reflection coefficient for Transverse electric waves"""

### Reflection coefficient

def Ref_1(theta):

    n_1=1.33

    r_TE_1 = np.cos(theta) - np.sqrt(n_1**2 - np.sin(theta)**2)
    r_TE_1 = r_TE_1 / (r_TE_1 + 2*np.sqrt(n_1**2 - np.sin(theta)**2))

    return r_TE_1


###  transmission coefficient

def Trans_1(theta):

    n_2=1.5

    r_TE_2 = 2*np.cos(theta)
    r_TE_2 = r_TE_2 / (np.cos(theta) + np.sqrt(n_2**2 - np.sin(theta)**2))

    return r_TE_2


"""Define reflection coefficient for Transverse magnetic waves"""


### Reflection coefficient

def Ref_2(theta):

    n_1=1.33

    r_TM = np.sqrt(n_1**2 - np.sin(theta)**2) - n_1**2*np.cos(theta)
    r_TM = r_TM / (np.sqrt(n_1**2 - np.sin(theta)**2) + n_1**2*np.cos(theta))

    return r_TM


###  transmission coefficient

def Trans_2(theta):

    n_2=1.5

    r_TM_2 = 2*np.cos(theta)
    r_TM_2 = r_TM_2 / (np.cos(theta)*n_2**2+np.sqrt(n_2**2-np.sqrt(theta))**2)

    return r_TM_2


"Set Fontlabel, Fontaxis"
Fontlabel=12
Fontaxis=13

"Plot results"
plt.figure()
fig=plt.figure()

Hoek = np.linspace(0,90,1)
print(Trans_2(100*(180/np.pi)))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(221)
ax1.plot(Hoek,Ref_1(Hoek),'blue',linewidth=0.8)
plt.title('TE gepolariseerd licht bij Refrectie')
plt.xlabel('$Hoek (\Theta)$')
plt.ylabel('$Amplitude$')

ax2=fig.add_subplot(222)
ax2.plot(Hoek,Trans_1(Hoek),'red',linewidth=0.8)
plt.title('TE gepolariseerd licht bij Transmissie')
plt.xlabel('$Hoek (\Theta)$')
plt.ylabel('$Amplitude$')

ax3=fig.add_subplot(223)
ax3.plot(Hoek,Ref_2(Hoek),'green',linewidth=0.8)
plt.title('TM gepolariseerd licht bij Reflectie')
plt.xlabel('$Hoek (\Theta)$')
plt.ylabel('$Amplitude$')


ax4=fig.add_subplot(224)
ax4.plot(Hoek,Trans_2(Hoek),'black',linewidth=0.8)
plt.title('TM gepolariseerd licht bij Transmissie')
plt.xlabel('$Hoek (\Theta)$')
plt.ylabel('$Amplitude$')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.9)
#plt.show()
```

with this subplots I get the following bad formats. I don't know how to change the subplots margin so I don't get subplots which overlap each other.

[image]

Comment: Use `plt.tight_layout()` for automatic adjustments. Else, use `plt.subpots_adjust(...)` to specify the parameters to your needs. Concerning the data not be present in the plots, you need to plug in angles in radiants, instead of degrees into the functions. (Not sure if the functions themselves are correct though. They seem to be a lot more complicated than the ones one would use normally.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i tried `plt.tight_layout()` but i did not get satisfying adjusments. i tried `plt.subplots_adjust(top=1.5, bottom=0.18, left=1, right=1, hspace=0.4,
                    wspace=0.7)` and this worked but finding the right configuration is beginning to be a real challenge

Comment: those values are fractions of figure size. Making them larger than 1 does not make sense. Also choosing left==right does not make sense. Start with something like `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom=0.2, left=0.2, right=0.8, hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5)`. Also consider making the figure larger, `fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))`.

Comment: thanks, it worked with this configuration `plt.subplots_adjust(top=1.5,bottom=0.18, left=0.2, right=2, hspace=0.4,
    wspace=0.2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space between the subplots can be adjusted using the following codes

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top=1.5,bottom=0.18, left=0.2, right=2, hspace=0.4, wspace=0.2)
```